# Specific C++ template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code fragment:

```
template <class T>
struct ServicePtr
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> service;

    ~ServicePtr()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct ServicePtrDeleter
{
    void operator()(ServicePtr<T>* ref) const
    {
        if (ref->service.get())
        {
            if (IRunnable<T>* r=dynamic_cast<IRunnable<T>*>(ref->service.get()))
            {
                //std::cout << "Mark Thread Finished" << std::endl;
                r->stop();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
            }
        }

        delete ref;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ServiceCreator
{
    static std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > create()
    {
        std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > servicePtr(new ServicePtr<T>, ServicePtrDeleter< ServicePtr<T> >());
        servicePtr->service.reset(new T);
        if (IRunnable<T>* r=dynamic_cast<IRunnable<T>*>(servicePtr->service.get()))
        {
            r->setSelfPtr(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IRunnable<T>>(servicePtr->service));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        }
        return servicePtr;
    }
};
```

`ServiceCreator<T>` , with T may or may not be derivated from IRunnable.
I get the following compiler error(GCC 4.6.1):

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../.. /../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/memory:86,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/thread:40,
             from main.cc:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In constructor 'std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(_Ptr, _Deleter) [with _Ptr = ServicePtr<LogWriter>*, _Deleter = ServicePtrDeleter<ServicePtr<LogWriter> >, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:771:37:   instantiated from 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter) [with  _Tp1 = ServicePtr<LogWriter>, _Deleter =  ServicePtrDeleter<ServicePtr<LogWriter> >, _Tp =  ServicePtr<LogWriter>, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp =  (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:128:37:   instantiated from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter) [with _Tp1 =  ServicePtr<LogWriter>, _Deleter =  ServicePtrDeleter<ServicePtr<LogWriter> >, _Tp = ServicePtr<LogWriter>]'
ServiceCreator.h:45:102:   instantiated from 'static std::shared_ptr<ServicePtr<U> > ServiceCreator<T>::create() [with T = LogWriter]'
main.cc:114:27:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:480:8: error: no match for call to '(ServicePtrDeleter<ServicePtr<LogWriter> >) (ServicePtr<LogWriter>*&)'
ServiceCreator.h:19:8: note: candidate is:
ServiceCreator.h:21:7: note: void ServicePtrDeleter<T>::operator()(ServicePtr<T>*) const [with T = ServicePtr<LogWriter>]
ServiceCreator.h:21:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ServicePtr<LogWriter>*' to 'ServicePtr<ServicePtr<LogWriter> >*'
```

Why `ServicePtrDeleter::operator()` gets instantiated with `ServicePtr< ServicePtr<T> >`? I just want to get T, inside `operator()`, so I can test whether it implements `IRunnable` or not.

main.cc:114 is `auto logWriter=LogWriter::create();` It is a global variable.

```
class LogWriter:
        public ServiceCreator<LogWriter>,
        public IRunnable<LogWriter>,
{
....
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? (Edit your question and add direct question to the end of it)

Comment: I am fixing the question now. You guys are just too quick.

Comment: In main.cc, how do you use these classes? Can you show us the code around line 114 (where the error originates)?

Comment: Any reason you have a `shared_ptr` inside a `shared_ptr`... ?

Comment: @DragomirIvanov: No, _you_ pressed "Submit Question" too quickly.

Comment: Yes. Inner shared_ptr is hold by IRunnable itself(pointer to self).
When all IRunnable clients are gone, outer shared_ptr tells IRunnable to initiate stop sequence, but not delete the IRunnable object yet. When IRunnable finishes, it resets its shared_ptr, so it deletes itself.
I.e. outer shared_ptr is hold by all IRunnable clients. inner shared_ptr is held by all clients+IRunnable itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServicePtrDeleter` is instantiated here:

```
std::shared_ptr< ServicePtr<T> > servicePtr(new ServicePtr<T>, ServicePtrDeleter< ServicePtr<T> >());
```

The template parameter given to `ServicePtrDeleter` is `ServicePtr<T>`.

When you replace the template parameter with `ServicePtr<T>` in `operator()` of  `ServicePtrDeleter`, you end up with a `ServicePtr< ServicePtr<T> >` parameter.

You probably just wanted to use a `T` template parameter in the instantiation, since `ServicePtrDeleter` wraps that into a `ServicePtr` itself:

```
... servicePtr(new ServicePtr<T>, ServicePtrDeleter<T>());
```

Comment: OMG. Yes, this fixes the compilation error, and on the first sight works. Before I this answer acceped, can you explain, why opetator()(ServicePtr<T>*), didn't got specialized. As I understand C++ typesystem it pick the most appropriate match. When I pass ServicePtr<T>* to operator(), shouldn't C++ understand that this is matched and extract T from it? Or I am just mistaken:

Comment: This is because you're attempting to specialize or instantiate a template struct/class rather than a template function ... with a struct/class template, there is no matching involved unless you specifically create a separate specialized struct/class with the specialized template parameters.  For instance, `template<> struct ServiceCreator<LogWriter> { ... };`.  Also the C++ compiler can't deduce the template parameters from the return type, only from the arguments to a function, so even if you made `create` a template function, you'd have to specify the template arguments.

Comment: There is no specialization involved. You have just a class template that, when instantiated with some type `X`, will have a `void operator()(ServicePtr<X>*) const`. It doesn't matter what type `X` is.